Queriendo hacer un reporte con fpdf181, me sale el error Call to undefined function each()

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mi_tienda2\reportes\Factura.php:359 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mi_tienda2\reportes\exFactura.php(62): PDF_Invoice->addCols(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mi_tienda2\reportes\Factura.php on line 359
C:\xampp\htdocs\mi_tienda2\reportes\Factura.php:359

function addCols( $tab )
{
    global $colonnes;
    
    $r1  = 10;
    $r2  = $this->w - ($r1 * 2) ;
    $y1  = 75;
    $y2  = $this->h - 50 - $y1;
    $this->SetXY( $r1, $y1 );
    $this->Rect( $r1, $y1, $r2, $y2, "D");
    $this->Line( $r1, $y1+6, $r1+$r2, $y1+6);
    $colX = $r1;
    /*Linea 359*/$colonnes = $tab;
    while ( list( $lib, $pos ) = each ($tab) )
    {
        $this->SetXY( $colX, $y1+2 );
        $this->Cell( $pos, 1, $lib, 0, 0, "C");
        $colX += $pos;
        $this->Line( $colX, $y1, $colX, $y1+$y2);
    }
}

C:\xampp\htdocs\mi_tienda2\reportes\exFactura.php(62)
//establecemos las columnas que va tener lña seccion donde mostramos los detalles de la venta
$cols=array( "CODIGO"=>23,
             "DESCRIPCION"=>78,
             "CANTIDAD"=>22,
             "P.U."=>25,
             "DSCTO"=>20,
             "SUBTOTAL"=>22);
/*Linea 62*/$pdf->addCols( $cols);
$cols=array( "CODIGO"=>"L",
             "DESCRIPCION"=>"L",
             "CANTIDAD"=>"C",
             "P.U."=>"R",
             "DSCTO"=>"R",
             "SUBTOTAL"=>"C" );
$pdf->addLineFormat( $cols);
$pdf->addLineFormat($cols); 


El error lo describe claramente:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each() in...
La función each() no está definida. O en palabras más simples, no existe!
La función each() está obsoleta a partir de PHP 7.2.0 y ha sido eliminada en PHP 8.0.0.  Debes reemplazarla por un foreach para asegurar la compatibilidad con versiones más recientes de PHP.
Si no me equivoco, y por favor revisa, el while debería ser:
foreach ($tab as $lib => $pos) {
    $this->SetXY($colX, $y1 + 2);
    $this->Cell($pos, 1, $lib, 0, 0, "C");
    $colX += $pos;
    $this->Line($colX, $y1, $colX, $y1 + $y2);
}


muchas gracias, hare la corrección

que versión de php estabas usando?
